# android dynamic created checkbox checking detection

Tags: android

i have created a list of checkbox dynamically in my app..i want to detect which check box is clicked ...please help
here is my code..

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_bid);
  String[] sh=item_list();
  int array_length=jArray.length();
  LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyout);

  for(int c=0; c<jArray.length();c++){
    CheckBox chk=new CheckBox(this);
    chk.setId(c+1);
    chk.setText("Click to add values");
    chk.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    linearLayout.addView(chk);
  }

  for(a = 1;a<=array_length;a++){
    CheckBox  satView = (CheckBox)findViewById(a);  
    satView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
        String s="x"+a;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not creating check box dynamically.. You are recreating single check box in for loop. It may work if you change it to CheckBox  satView = new CheckBox();

Comment: so what is happening this code not working, error, exception??

Comment: NO, Its new Checkbox(), its not same checkbox :) Looks like never trierd to add a click listener

Comment: i think this is listener code... satView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
        String s="x"+a;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
      }
    });

Comment: @saa Its not working ...i cant understand how to use  CheckBox satView = new CheckBox(); it is getting me error "The constructor CheckBox() is undefined"

Comment: @saa Ya,ther it is :)

Comment: @Brett check my answer bellow

Comment: Try the answer given by Charan Pai. It will work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this ..

```
  @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_bid);
          String[] sh=item_list();
          int array_length=jArray.length();
          LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyout);

          for(int c=0; c<jArray.length();c++){
            CheckBox chk=new CheckBox(this);
            chk.setId(c+1);
            chk.setText("Click to add values");
            chk.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
              @Override
              public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
               String s="x"+buttonView.getId();
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                switch(buttonView.getId()){

                  case 1: // do something on 1st checkbox
                        break;

                  case 2: //do something on 2nd  checkbox
                       break;

                //And SO ON for all checkboes
            }  
           }
          });
            linearLayout.addView(chk);
          }


        }
```

If `SetId(Int)` is not working then you can use `setTag(int)` and `getTag()` instead.

Comment: its only working for 1st checkbox..rest of the checkbox are not functioning

Comment: You wrote code for all switch cases there ? check my edit now, should give out some Toast msg for each checkboes .

Comment: Awesome this is what I am searching for Hours...!